# Which types of Windows 8 STORE apps requires Accessibility test?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, appstore-approval

We are developing one Windows 8 STORE app in C# and it is a type of Network Scanner Tool.
Is our app requires any Accessibility test before going to submit the app?
Clearly let me know, which type of apps requires the Accessibility test?

Comment: What makes you think accessibility testing is required?  That it entirely left up to the developer, if you don't want that market share, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: if you don't want that market share, feel free to ignore it.ok..But, which types of apps better to test it?

Answer (score 2):

During the process of submitting your app to the Windows Store, there is a checkbox that you can check if you want to declare your app as meeting accessibility guidelines.  This is optional.  See [Declaring your app as accessible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694072.aspx) for more information on when and how to do this.

Comment: Marsman: I have observed this checkbox already,but my doubt is, how can i confirm it's required for my app? or is it limited for some apps (like games, music, etc..)?

Comment: It's not required.  Look at the link that I posted above.  If you take the extra steps described in that link, then you can check the box that you have tested your app and it is accessible.  Then your app becomes easily found by users who filter by the Accessible filter.